# Perl vs. PHP to tar files on a remote server then move them to another remote server

Tags: php, perl, tar

I need to create a web application that tars files on a remote server then moves those files to another server. I am new to scripting languages and was wondering if there are advantages to php or perl for this type of application.

Comment: No PHP nor Perl is required here. Shell scripting and serverfault it is.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  Both will get the job done just as good as the other.  The bottleneck of both will be connecting to the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

PHP was originally derived from Perl, so the syntax between the two are very similar. It's all a matter of taste.

PHP is nice because many Apache servers are setup to allow you to embed PHP code inside your HTML pages. This makes PHP very popular in building things like CMS systems and bulletin boards.

I personally think that the PHP syntax is sloppy. There's way too many specific functions and they're not clearly thought out. The syntax changes from one function to another. I guess it's part of PHP's group based philosophy where a lot of people add a lot of features. I also like Perl's `use strict` and `use warnings` pragmas which I find save me a lot of grief.

But, as I said, when it comes to webpage development, PHP is ahead of Perl.

(Yes, I know about modperl, but that's not usually installed in most Apache servers).

I'd say to go ahead and learn both. I believe the Perl books are some of the best written programming guides I've seen. I haven't been too thrilled with the PHP ones. Maybe its because Perl is just more established, so the documentation has been better defined.

Then again, if you're going to learn something, maybe you should try Python. I'm not a fan of Python, but its the up and coming language that most people are learning these days. Google uses Python extensively. And, don't forget Ruby which has the webbased Rails platform that's very popular.

By the way, what you want to do isn't part of the default language, but most languages have modules that are easily installable. For example, you'll need `Archive::Tar` and `LWP` for Perl. These can be downloaded from the [CPAN](http://cpan.perl.com) module archive.

It's going to take you a while to pick up enough of any language to do what you want, so be patient and have fun.

Comment: just to clarify, the concept of "embedding PHP code in HTML pages" is called templating and is definitely not unique to PHP - it exists in Java (JSP), Windows stuff (ASP I think) as well as Perl (plethora of templating solutions, from EmbPerl to Template Toolkit to ...). See http://perl.apache.org/docs/tutorials/tmpl/comparison/comparison.html . Matter of fact I would't have been surprized if PHPs templating was cloned from either JSPs or EmbPerl

Comment: @DVK The history of PHP is rather interesting. PHP was was interpreted by the Perl CGI scripts before it became a full fledge language. That's why the two languages have so much in common. Although there are other ways of embedding code in a web page, PHP is probably the most common. In fact, it's the whole reason why the language exists in the first place. PHP actually predates JSP and ASP, so it might be one of the first embedded languages.

Comment: Archive::Tar for several years is a core module, so there is no need to install it unless you have an old Perl. For embedding Perl into HTML, there is no need for mod_perl, Template Toolkit or HTML::Mason is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need this ssh extension http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

It support calling `ssh` using `ssh2_connect`.
And you can bundle with `tar`, `scp`, or even `rsync`

Comment: What has this answer to do with the question? He is not asking "how to do it in PHP".